# How to detect Windows is locked?

Tags: winapi, win32com

How to detect Windows is locked (Win+L or locked by screensaver)? Is it possible?

Comment: This is an old question, but there are new answer: [For windows 7 and abowe WTS API can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115698/2148229)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no documented way to check if the session is locked.  There is however a way to detect that the session is *getting* locked.  Use WTSRegisterSessionNotification(), you'll get a WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE message with the WTS_SESSION_LOCK value when the workstation is being locked.

If you are planning to do this from a service then be sure to google "session 0 isolation" to find out why that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm reading this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310153. I will try the code later.

Comment: Using `WTSRegisterSessionNotification()` is the only option.  MSDN says as much (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875.aspx): "There is no function you can call to determine whether the workstation is locked. To receive notification when the user logs in, use the `WTSRegisterSessionNotification()` function to receive `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` messages."  Services that use a `HandlerEx` SCM callback, as opposed to a `Handler` SCM callback, can receive `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` notifications from `WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`.

Answer (score 1):

WTSRegisterSessionNotification() will require the elevated privileges on Windows 10/11.

Call WTSQuerySessionInformation with WTS_INFO_CLASS set to WTSSessionInfoEx.

struct _WTSINFOEX_LEVEL1_A has a member, LONG SessionFlags, which indicates whether the calling session is locked or not.