# In Python 3, how can I tell if Windows is locked?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

How can I check whether a Windows OS workstation is locked? (e.g. Win+L or choosing the lock option after Ctrl+Alt+Del.)

I want something like `ctypes.windll.user32.isWorkstationLocked()`.

Comment: What version of Windows is it?

Comment: does any of below answers worked..??

Answer (score 13):

This code worked today for me on four different Windows 7 and 10 machines, try something similar:

```
import ctypes
import time
user32 = ctypes.windll.User32
time.sleep(5)
#
#print(user32.GetForegroundWindow())
#
if (user32.GetForegroundWindow() % 10 == 0): print('Locked')
# 10553666 - return code for unlocked workstation1
# 0 - return code for locked workstation1
#
# 132782 - return code for unlocked workstation2
# 67370 -  return code for locked workstation2
#
# 3216806 - return code for unlocked workstation3
# 1901390 - return code for locked workstation3
#
# 197944 - return code for unlocked workstation4
# 0 -  return code for locked workstation4
#
else: print('Unlocked')
```

Edit: Also, this one works today:

```
import subprocess
import time
time.sleep(5)
process_name='LogonUI.exe'
callall='TASKLIST'
outputall=subprocess.check_output(callall)
outputstringall=str(outputall)
if process_name in outputstringall:
    print("Locked.")
else: 
    print("Unlocked.")
```

Comment: Code from the edit section works for Windows 10 Pro like a charm.

Comment: Edit code works great. I assume the sleep is just so you have time to lock the screen and test.

Comment: @Ruben, yes exactly for that. Glad it works for you!

Comment: the original user32 doesn't work for me - it sometimes reports as locked even if it is not. Windows 10 Pro

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Other windows such as magnifier (Win+U) can become the foreground window while Windows 10 is locked.

Answer (score 6):

A hack I discovered to get around to see if Windows 10 is locked is to look at the running processes using `psutil`. You then search to see whether or not `LogonUI.exe` is running. This process only runs when a user has a locked session.

Note: If you use "switch users" this process will be shown as running and this workaround will not work. Windows actually spawns multiple `LogonUI.exe` processes, one per logged on locked user. It is only useful when there is only one person logged on at a time.

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if(proc.name() == "LogonUI.exe"):
        print ("Locked")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the window on top, when the session is locked, the function return 0.

```
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.windll.User32

def isLocked():
    return user32.GetForegroundWindow() == 0
```

Comment: This is false for me in Windows 10 Pro. When locked, the hwnd process ID is a changing number with the title "Windows Default Lock Screen". It's only hwnd == 0 when I press Enter to put the password in. I used a few lines from this example to fetch the title and compare it to either 0, "", or the title above.

http://pixomania.net/programming/python-getting-the-title-of-windows-getting-their-processes-and-their-commandlines-using-ctypes-and-win32/

Comment: @JamesKoss try the solution below this one, it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
import time
import ctypes

user32 = ctypes.windll.User32
OpenDesktop = user32.OpenDesktopA
SwitchDesktop = user32.SwitchDesktop
DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x0100

while 1:
  hDesktop = OpenDesktop ("default", 0, False, DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP)
  result = SwitchDesktop (hDesktop)
  if result:
    print "Unlocked"
    time.sleep (1.0)
  else:
    print time.asctime (), "still locked"
    time.sleep (2)
```

Comment: @IvanBaksheev, are you using Python 3? This should be written to use `OpenDesktopW` and the explicit unicode literal `u"Default"`.

Comment: Note that the "Default" desktop may not be the active application desktop, so switching to it is a side effect. I don't know how to get the current application desktop. `OpenInputDesktop` tries to open the active desktop, but that could be "Winlogon" if the workstation is locked (requires SYSTEM). It's not telling us what the WindowStation's active *application* desktop is. winlogon.exe tracks this, but I don't know an API to query it.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Check these 4 lines..

returns the application name which is on the screen.. if window is locked returns the string - Windows Default Lock Screen.

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
import time
time.sleep(5)
# lock the system or open the application for a check
print(GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()))
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Other windows such as magnifier (Win+U) can become the foreground window while Windows 10 is locked.

Comment: For other locale, the returned string could be different.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`LockWorkStation()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> There is no function you can call to determine whether the workstation is locked.

Not a Python limitation, but the system itself.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me on Windows 10 Pro is getting the foreground window:

```
whnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
(_, pid) = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(whnd)
handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
filename = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(handle, 0)
window_text = win32gui.GetWindowText(whnd)
```

This returns `Windows Default Lock Screen` as window title and `C:\Windows\SystemApp\Microsoft.LockApp_<randomcharacters>\LockApp.exe` as filename when locked.

However, as James Koss mentioned, GetForeGroundWindow will return 0 if the user is typing their password. There are also other (non-locked) situations where the current ForegroundWindow is 0, so this cannot be relied upon.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Other windows such as magnifier (Win+U) can become the foreground window while Windows 10 is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Stardidi answer, this worked for me (Windows 10 Pro):

```
import time
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con
import win32process

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    _, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())

    try:
        handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
        filename = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(handle, 0)
    except Exception as _e:
        filename = "LockApp.exe"
        del _e

    current_status = "locked" if "LockApp" in filename else "unlocked"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer here, but you can do this via Session Tracking.

From the [LockWorkStation() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-lockworkstation):

> There is no function you can call to determine whether the workstation is locked. To receive notification when the user logs in, use the [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification) function to receive [WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/wm-wtssession-change) messages. You can use session notifications to track the desktop state so you know whether it is possible to interact with the user.

Begin by registering session notifications to a window of your program.

```py
def register(handle: HWND) -> bool:
    """
    @param handle: handle for your message window.
    When registered, Windows Messages related to session event changes will be
    sent to the message window.
    @returns: True is session tracking is successfully registered.

    Blocks until Windows accepts session tracking registration.

    Every call to this function must be paired with a call to unregister.

    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification
    """
    # OpenEvent handle must be closed with CloseHandle.
    eventObjectHandle: HANDLE = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenEventW(
        # Blocks until WTS session tracking can be registered.
        # Windows needs time for the WTS session tracking service to initialize.
        # must ensure that the WTS session tracking service is ready before trying to register
        SYNCHRONIZE,  # DWORD dwDesiredAccess
        False,  # BOOL bInheritHandle - sub-processes do not need to inherit this handle
        # According to the docs, when the Global\TermSrvReadyEvent global event is set,
        # all dependent services have started and WTSRegisterSessionNotification can be successfully called.
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification#remarks
        "Global\\TermSrvReadyEvent"  # LPCWSTR lpName - The name of the event object.
    )
    if not eventObjectHandle:
        error = ctypes.WinError()
        log.error("Unexpected error waiting to register session tracking.")
        return False

    registrationSuccess = ctypes.windll.wtsapi32.WTSRegisterSessionNotification(handle, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(eventObjectHandle)

    if registrationSuccess:
        log.debug("Registered session tracking")
    else:
        error = ctypes.WinError()
        if error.errno == RPC_S_INVALID_BINDING:
            log.error(
                "WTS registration failed. "
                "Waited successfully on TermSrvReadyEvent to ensure that WTS is ready to allow registration. "
                "Cause of failure unknown. "
            )
        else:
            log.error("Unexpected error registering session tracking.")

    return registrationSuccess


def unregister(handle: HWND) -> None:
    """
    This function must be called once for every call to register.
    If unregistration fails, session tracking may not work properly until the session can be unregistered in a new instance.

    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsunregistersessionnotification
    """
    if ctypes.windll.wtsapi32.WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(handle):
        log.debug("Unregistered session tracking")
    else:
        error = ctypes.WinError()
        log.error("Unexpected error unregistering session tracking.")
```

In your Window Message handler for the window, when you receive `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`, handle `WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK` and `WTS_SESSION_LOCK` events to track the state of Windows being locked.

A similar answer here might give more context on [handling windows messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607270/detect-if-windows-workstation-is-locked-in-pyqt5-application).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the second proposed approach from the [macok's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57258754/8534396) answer (usage of the subprocess library).
At least it is the only way in which I managed to solve the same problem...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34561430)