# How to know whether Win10 is screen locked or not?

Tags: python, window

I know that we can lock screen of Win10 with python code below:

```
user32.LockWorkStation()
```

But how can I know that whether the screen is locked at certain time?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding there is no ONE api function to do it with.
But I advice You to take a look on this relevant link:
[In Python 3, how can I tell if Windows is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514644/in-python-3-how-can-i-tell-if-windows-is-locked)

Good luck!