# What is the difference between WTS_SESSIONSTATE_UNKNOWN and WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to determine the current session state using the *Win32 API* [`::WTSQuerySessionInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(WTSAPI32%2FWTSQuerySessionInformation);k(WTSQuerySessionInformation);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true) function by querying for *SessionFlags* of the [`WTSINFOEX_LEVEL1`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) structure according to the answers to [C++: check if computer is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326685/c-check-if-computer-is-locked).

On my machine (Windows 10 1703) *SesssionFlags* can reach only two (of three documented) values: **WTS_SESSIONSTATE_UNLOCK** and **WTS_SESSIONSTATE_UNKNOWN**. The latter seems to mean the same as the expected **WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK** which I cannot reach, neither through `<WinKey>+<L>` nor by programmatically locking the session through [`::LockWorkStation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875(v=vs.85).aspx).

So my questions are:

1. Does **WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK** exist?
2. If yes, then how can I reach that state?
3. If yes, what is the difference between both states (`LOCK` and `UNKNOWN`)?

According to [SessionChangeReason Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.sessionchangereason(v=vs.110).aspx) the .NET Framework distinguishes (correctly?) between just two corresponding states `SessionUnlock` and `SessionUnlock`. So the state of a session is triple or binary?

Comment: It is not possible to detect that the secure desktop is currently displayed.  The .NET Framework avoids that problem by detecting changes in the session state with WTSRegisterSessionNotification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would think that `WTS_SESSIONSTATE_UNKNOWN` means that the state is unknown and you should not interpret it as locked nor unlocked. It seems this member has a sorry history, MSDN says

> **Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7:**  Due to a code defect, the usage of the WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK and WTS_SESSIONSTATE_UNLOCK flags is reversed. That is, WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK indicates that the session is unlocked, and WTS_SESSIONSTATE_UNLOCK indicates the session is locked.

Because the member is named Session**Flags** and MSDN says "This can be one or more of the following values" one could imagine that more flags could be added over time and you should actually be doing:

```
isUnlocked = SessionFlags & WTS_SESSIONSTATE_UNLOCK;
```

(and the logic reversed on Windows 7). I don't think anyone does this so I doubt Microsoft will ever add more flags but you never know.

On my Windows 8 and 10.0.17134 machines it returns `WTS_SESSIONSTATE_UNLOCK` normally and `WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK` when I press <kbd>Win+L</kbd> so it is possible you are doing something wrong?

I don't know what happens if a Windows 7+ machine tries to ask a Vista machine, maybe you get `WTS_SESSIONSTATE_UNKNOWN` or maybe the entire call fails because Vista does not support `WTSSessionInfoEx`.

The accepted answer in the question you linked to tells you to use [`WTSRegisterSessionNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841(v=vs.85).aspx) and it will provide you with the same values as `SessionChangeReason` and you don't have to pull to detect changes.

Comment: You're right: I have reviewed my code and I saw that I mixed-up `WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK` with `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`'s `WTS_SESSION_LOCK`. Having fixed the typo, `WTS_SESSION**STATE**_LOCK` discovered itself. In my case `WTSRegisterSessionNotification`is not acceptable since I have to know the initial state (before any session change).