# windows lock and unlock event in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I want to create a program that "locks" my work station as soon as I leave or move away from my computer. And automatically starts again as soon as the user login.

I'm using Opencv to track my movement and its working.

now I want to know how can I automatically start a function again as soon as the user login using c++

I'm using

```
LockWorkStation();
```

to lock my system

I have a C# implementation for it which I got from
[Programmatically Determine a Duration of a Locked Workstation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980/programmatically-determine-a-duration-of-a-locked-workstation/52102#52102)

```
const int SessionUnlockParam = 0x8;

if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == SessionUnlockParam)
{OnSessionUnlock(); // Do something when unlocked
}

void OnSessionUnlock()
{
 // Do something......  
}
```

can someone tell me how to to do this in C++
and which libraries to use

or

How can I access Event IDs in C++
such as: " Event_ID = 4801 - The workstation was unlocked".

for windows 8

Comment: Technically, asking for libraries is off-topic for stack overflow. However, I see no reason why the rest of your question wouldn't be on topic. I don't know the answer, though.

Comment: I don't believe this is actually a duplicate of checking if the workstation is locked. Muhammad wants to be notified of session changes, the linked solution would require polling.

Comment: I have tried This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326685/c-check-if-computer-is-locked

But It doesn't work on visual studio 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a window to receive events for session changes using [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification).

Then listen for WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE with a wParam value of WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK.

Comment: Thanks for an early response
actually I'm with C++ 
I'll be grateful If u could tell me how to implement it

Comment: do i have to download or configure any .dll or library

Comment: You do need to link to the library Wtsapi32.lib.

Comment: already did it.

Comment: BOOL WTSRegisterSessionNotification(
      HWND  hWnd,
      DWORD dwFlags
    );

Comment: what values I have to give as argument?

Comment: See the link for details. It takes the window handle that will receive the events and a flag whose value is either NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION or NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS. Assuming you have a standard win32 message loop and WndProc set up for the window handle you can receive the messages there.

Comment: hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

how to implement ** HINSTANCE hInstance **

Comment: You can simply pass in GetModuleHandle(NULL) for the HINSTANCE parameter to use your program's own module/instance.

Comment: WTSRegisterSessionNotification() is returning same value before lock  and after lock

Comment: The return value only indicates whether or not the function succeeded, then your window handle receives messages when the session status changes (eg. locked, unlocked).

Comment: how to get these messages? and what data type I have to use for message ? will Strings work?

Comment: You don't define the type for the messages, they are unsigned integers. See these two tutorial pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/window-messages and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/writing-the-window-procedure